# Is it possible to get flat (unboxed) structures in Java?

Tags: java

I want to create a structure with several arrays inside and possibly other structures.
Is it possible To have "flat" memory layout for this? I.e. One piece of memory witout pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so.  Outside of using one big array for everything and writing your own code to represent objects as arrays of, say, bytes, which is a bad idea.  In Java, everything but primitives is a reference automatically; you can't work directly with arrays or objects.

Why do you need a flat memory chunk?  If you're worried about memory allocation issues, consider some sort of object pool.

Comment: *"In Java, everything but literals is a reference automatically..."* No, everything but *primitives* are referenced by, um, reference. But in (say) `int a = 42 * 10;`, `a` is neither a reference nor a literal, it's a primitive.

Comment: And +1. This is the correct answer: As you said, no, you can't do that barring declaring a massive single-dimensional `byte` array and doing all of the other work yourself (blech).

Comment: yeah, sorry, I meant to say primitives.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I want to hear more about why you want this. What are you doing that needs this level of optimization?

Comment: I was thinking about porting Libego (Very very optimized c++, no asm though) to java to see the performance. The slowest thing are if mispredictions and memory access. Any pointer indirection slow things down.

Comment: What about accessing such structures in C using foreign function interface?

Comment: You could use C... probably the best way to do this kind of thing if you absolutely have to.  The overhead of trying to maintain your own byte array would probably make it way too complicated.

Here's a starting point for learning how to interface with C using the Java Native Interface:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get in memory or functionality is an array of primitives, such as byte[].  This is how MemoryImageSource and BufferedImage work to relatively efficiently store and blit images.